# startup application using adminstrator privilege vc++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-installer

Am working on a vc++ background application which installs in the program files folder. It works fine when it was manually started, it creates xml file in the same folder. But however the application is not creating the file when it was configured to startup.

Even when I provide the requireAdministrator privilege it is not creating the file at the startup.

This is same as the issue with [Granting administrator privileges to an application launched at startup without UAC prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640056/granting-administrator-privileges-to-an-application-launched-at-startup-without)

but when program runs as Administrator it doesn't start at startup, this is my problem

But am working for a solution in vc++.

Please help am working on this more than a week

Comment: Windows doesn't allow this anymore.  When you put a manifested EXE in the startup  folder / run / runonce keys, Windows will skip it to provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a proper manifest to your project?
In VC++ you must add one(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Yes I created a manifest and linked it. If I provide the requireAdministrator privilege, the application itself is not coming on startup. what should I do to start the application as administrator on startup

Comment: when program runs as Administrator it doesn't start at startup, this is my problem

Answer (score 1):

Move the XML file to ProgramData (`CSIDL_APPDATA`).

Comment: Am updating the xml file every minute using tinyxml. I can only able to save the xml in application path  --> doc.SaveFile( "Smartmeter.xml" ); I cant able to save xml in another path.

Comment: @user1441251: Wrong, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376468/visual-studio-2005-and-tinyxml-xml-file-location. Another solution would be to change the Current Working Directory to `CSIDL_APPDATA` before calling `SaveFile`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have UAC enabled (i.e. UAC prompt appears). If that so, you would see it always when you start from Explorer, and will not see from Admin mode Visual Studio (since VS is elevated), and hence your process would be elevated.

But, when your process starts, the UAC won't appear, and your application will fail to start. It is best bet **not** to make your application requiring Administrator rights (why do you need?). You can save the data in some other folder.

If you must, you may need to create a service, which would start your application in elevated-mode (yes, without any UAC prompt).

Do check the system event reporting for your application, since this cannot be easily debugged.